# Keyframe animation is lost at FBX export

Tags: animation

I have a short keyframe stop motion animation with a couple of objects. Some have a parent-child relation. 
In Blender it plays just fine, but when I export it to FBX, (and reimport it to Blender) some animations are missing and the parent's animation is duplicated to the child objects animations, so the child anims are lost.
I didn't use any bones, since the animations are all just rotations on local and custom transformation orientations.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've realized I have to bake the animations, so that solved. 
But now I have the children of the parent object all over the place in FBX.